# Is there anyway to create a forcefully directory even if it exists at the source location

Tags: unix

Is there any way to create a directory even if it exists. I want to override the existing directory with newly directory. supose i have a directory dir1(which has some contents inside it). Now i want to create the same directory as a dir1 ,but it's not happening for me. I don't know how do i go about it?

Comment: Should the previous contents of the folder be removed?

Comment: You can always do an `rm -rf` and then create the directory with `mkdir -p`.

Comment: Oh, you probably want to say `mkdir dir1 2>/dev/null`

Comment: yes previous contents should be removed @Francisco

Comment: You can say `mkdir dir || ( rm -rf dir && mkdir dir )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the only way to achieve that is to use rm to delete the folder and mkdir to create it after.

You can create a previous check to only remove the folder if it exits with something like:

```
[[ -d "$FOLDER" ]] && rm -rf "$FOLDER"
mkdir -p "$FOLDER"
```

or in one sentence

```
{ [[ -d "$FOLDER" ]] && rm -rf "$FOLDER"; } ; mkdir -p "$FOLDER";
```

If you want to keep it simple:

```
rm -rf "$FOLDER" && mkdir -p "$FOLDER"
```